# cómo descargar archivos de un servidor a mi pc con ssh?

Tags: debian, zsh

Necesito descargar unos archivos que están en un servidor a mi pc pero no he podido hacerlo, y me gustaría por ssh (no me recomiendan ftp). Antes usaba `Deepin` y con `nautilus` podía conectarme, pero ahora uso debian y no lo he logrado.

He intentado con `ssh://root@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2014/var/www/html/` pero no entra al directorio html ni me pide la contraseña.

[image: pantalla1]

pero por terminal sí ingreso al servidor con `ssh -p 2014 root@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx` y me pide la contraseña y todo normal.

El problema es que si hago `scp -P 2014 -r root@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/yyyyftp/web/10/15/ /media/caro/my_dde` se demora mucho la transmisión de archivos y antes con nautilus en mi deepin era muy rápido.

Comment: y si intentas con el comando wget?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quizás tengas problemas con el software de archivos de debian. Haz intentado con FileZilla?

FileZilla también tiene conexiones con SSH y es mucho más cómodo (y estable). Yo lo uso para descargar desde mis servidores de Amazon AWS ya que con el método no permite ingresar otro tipo de parámetros de conexión.

Además puedes gestionar múltiples host, vps, en la configuración... puede ser un poco amenza de interfaz, pero de funcionalidad es perfecto.